# Unzipping encrypted compressed report from Amazon Selling Partner

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, request, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am using the `getReport` operation to fetch the `documentId`, which later I use to download the report document itself which is encrypted and compressed.

The code looks like this:

```
const documentData = await this.sellingPartner.callAPI({
  operation: "getReportDocument",
  endpoint: "reports",
  path: { reportDocumentId: reportData.reportDocumentId }
})

const request = https.get(documentData.url, function(res) {
  const data = [];
  res.on("data", chunk => data.push(chunk));
  res.on("end", () => {
    const key = new Buffer.from(documentData.encryptionDetails.key, 'base64')
    const initializationVector = new Buffer.from(documentData.encryptionDetails.initializationVector, 'base64')

    const input = Buffer.concat(data)

    let result;
    try {
      result = aes.decryptText(
        aes.CIPHERS.AES_256,
        key,
        initializationVector,
        input
      )
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }

    console.log(">>>>")
    console.log(result)

    zlib.gunzip(result, (err, unzipped) => {
      debugger
    });
  });
}
```

The current error I am getting is from zlib:

```
Error: incorrect header check
    at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (node:zlib:189:17)
```

I am getting the same even if I pass the unencrypted value directly to zlib.

There is a [Sample Java code example](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/reports-api-v2021-06-30-use-case-guide#sample-code-java) in the docs, but I cannot understand very well where they do the decryption: before unzipping or after?

In any case, what is the right way to solve this: unzip and decrypt or decrypt and unzip? The former does not work at all, the latter almost works but fails at the unzipping part.

How can I solve the unzip problem?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:
Decrypt first and then decompress if compression type is specified.

Longer answer:

After a little research I stumbled upon this example (sadly written in python not in javascript) but it covers the steps to do in more detail.

https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/issues/186#issuecomment-756108550

It contains both compressed or not compressed cases.
Specifically for compressed it looks like this:

```
import gzip
import requests

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes

def ase_cbc_decryptor(key, iv, encryption):
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(base64.b64decode(key)), modes.CBC(base64.b64decode(iv)))
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
    decrypted_text = decryptor.update(encryption)
    unpadder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).unpadder()
    unpaded_text = unpadder.update(decrypted_text)
    return unpaded_text + unpadder.finalize()

def get_report_document_content(self, key, iv, url, compression_type=None):
    resp = requests.get(url=url)
    resp_content = resp.content

    decrypted_content = ase_cbc_decryptor(key=key, iv=iv, encryption=resp_content)

    if compression_type == 'GZIP':
       decrypted_content = gzip.decompress(decrypted_content)

    code = 'utf-8'
    if 'cp1252' in resp.headers.get('Content-Type', '').lower():
        code = 'Cp1252'
    return decrypted_content.decode(code)
```

P.S. keep in mind you need to use AES in CBC mode

Short example here:
https://gist.github.com/manuks/5cef1e536ef791e97b39

```
var keyhex = "8479768f48481eeb9c8304ce0a58481eeb9c8304ce0a5e3cb5e3cb58479768f4"; //length 32 

var blockSize = 16;

function encryptAES(input) {
    try {
        var iv = require('crypto').randomBytes(16);
        //console.info('iv',iv);
        var data = new Buffer(input).toString('binary');
        //console.info('data',data);
        
        key = new Buffer(keyhex, "hex");
        //console.info(key);
        var cipher = require('crypto').createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
        // UPDATE: crypto changed in v0.10

        // https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Api-changes-between-v0.8-and-v0.10 

        var nodev = process.version.match(/^v(\d+)\.(\d+)/);

        var encrypted;

        if( nodev[1] === '0' && parseInt(nodev[2]) < 10) {
            encrypted = cipher.update(data, 'binary') + cipher.final('binary');
        } else {
            encrypted =  cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'binary') +  cipher.final('binary');
        }

        var encoded = new Buffer(iv, 'binary').toString('hex') + new Buffer(encrypted, 'binary').toString('hex');

        return encoded;
    } catch (ex) {
      // handle error
      // most likely, entropy sources are drained
      console.error(ex);
    }
}
function decryptAES(encoded) {  
    var combined = new Buffer(encoded, 'hex');      

    key = new Buffer(keyhex, "hex");
    
    // Create iv
    var iv = new Buffer(16);
    
    combined.copy(iv, 0, 0, 16);
    edata = combined.slice(16).toString('binary');

    // Decipher encrypted data
    var decipher = require('crypto').createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);

    // UPDATE: crypto changed in v0.10
    // https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Api-changes-between-v0.8-and-v0.10 

    var nodev = process.version.match(/^v(\d+)\.(\d+)/);

    var decrypted, plaintext;
    if( nodev[1] === '0' && parseInt(nodev[2]) < 10) {  
        decrypted = decipher.update(edata, 'binary') + decipher.final('binary');    
        plaintext = new Buffer(decrypted, 'binary').toString('utf8');
    } else {
        plaintext = (decipher.update(edata, 'binary', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8'));
    }
    return plaintext;
}
var input="testing";

var encrypted = encryptAES(input);
console.info('encrypted:', encrypted);
var decryped = decryptAES(encrypted);
console.info('decryped:',decryped);
```